# using cameraView to show markers on a specific location

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, android-augmented-reality

I am working on a native android project in which i need to use augmented reality in a section.
It is a like a business application in which user get offers from company. 
Now the main part is the offers will get like we get Pokemon in PokemonGo app.
Also the offers will be shown to the user like the restaurants  shown in Yelp(Camera View).
Please suggest me what do i do?
Do I use unity for this or this kind of app can be build in eclipse/Android Studio.
I want to know how do I integrate Augmented reality in my native android app.
I don't have any experience in Unity.